# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'method'

Tags: python, machine-learning, typeerror, kaggle

```py
skewness = train_num.apply(lambda x: skew(x))
skewness = skewness[abs(skewness) > 0.5]
print(str(skewness.shape[0]) + " skewed numerical features to log transform")
skewed_features = skewness.index
train_num[skewed_features] = np.log1p(train_num[skewed_features])
```

I am a Newbie in ML and Python. I am working on a kernel from Kaggle. So far I have cleaned up the data and name a new column in the original data with the name train_num. Now when taking skew of the numerical features(train_num) so that to apply log on it and lessen the impact of outliers I am getting TypeError on the 1st line of this code block.
From what I see, I understand that apply can not work with float values but I don't quite see any other way.
Please help.
Thank you.

**Here is the complete error that I am getting.**

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-ceffe1b0bb84> in <module>
      2 # Inspired by Alexandru Papiu's script : https://www.kaggle.com/apapiu/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques/regularized-linear-models
      3 # As a general rule of thumb, a skewness with an absolute value > 0.5 is considered at least moderately skewed
----> 4 skewness = train_num.apply(lambda x: skew(x))
      5 skewness = skewness[abs(skewness) > 0.5]
      6 print(str(skewness.shape[0]) + " skewed numerical features to log transform")

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in apply(self, func, axis, raw, result_type, args, **kwds)
   6876             kwds=kwds,
   6877         )
-> 6878         return op.get_result()
   6879 
   6880     def applymap(self, func) -> "DataFrame":

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in get_result(self)
    184             return self.apply_raw()
    185 
--> 186         return self.apply_standard()
    187 
    188     def apply_empty_result(self):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in apply_standard(self)
    293 
    294             try:
--> 295                 result = libreduction.compute_reduction(
    296                     values, self.f, axis=self.axis, dummy=dummy, labels=labels
    297                 )

pandas\_libs\reduction.pyx in pandas._libs.reduction.compute_reduction()

pandas\_libs\reduction.pyx in pandas._libs.reduction.Reducer.get_result()

<ipython-input-16-ceffe1b0bb84> in <lambda>(x)
      2 # Inspired by Alexandru Papiu's script : https://www.kaggle.com/apapiu/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques/regularized-linear-models
      3 # As a general rule of thumb, a skewness with an absolute value > 0.5 is considered at least moderately skewed
----> 4 skewness = train_num.apply(lambda x: skew(x))
      5 skewness = skewness[abs(skewness) > 0.5]
      6 print(str(skewness.shape[0]) + " skewed numerical features to log transform")

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py in skew(a, axis, bias, nan_policy)
   1228         return mstats_basic.skew(a, axis, bias)
   1229 
-> 1230     m2 = moment(a, 2, axis)
   1231     m3 = moment(a, 3, axis)
   1232     zero = (m2 == 0)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py in moment(a, moment, axis, nan_policy)
   1040         return np.array(mmnt)
   1041     else:
-> 1042         return _moment(a, moment, axis)
   1043 
   1044 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py in _moment(a, moment, axis)
   1080 
   1081         # Starting point for exponentiation by squares
-> 1082         a_zero_mean = a - np.expand_dims(np.mean(a, axis), axis)
   1083         if n_list[-1] == 1:
   1084             s = a_zero_mean.copy()

<__array_function__ internals> in mean(*args, **kwargs)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py in mean(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
   3332             return mean(axis=axis, dtype=dtype, out=out, **kwargs)
   3333 
-> 3334     return _methods._mean(a, axis=axis, dtype=dtype,
   3335                           out=out, **kwargs)
   3336 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py in _mean(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
    149             is_float16_result = True
    150 
--> 151     ret = umr_sum(arr, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
    152     if isinstance(ret, mu.ndarray):
    153         ret = um.true_divide(

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'method'
```

Comment: What does x contain?

Comment: x is the values of train_num column.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with " skewness = train_num.apply(lambda x: skew(x)) " ? Are you trying to compute the skewness of the data stored in the train_num column? For this, you would need " skewness = train_num.skew() "  (But I am not sure if this is what you want to do. If not, could you explain better?)